# How to use serial.write() for SMA protocol

Tags: python, scale, pyserial

I need to send the SMA command < LF >W< CR > (sorry for the space between letter and <>) through my RS232 connection so when I press button in my application I will receive the data that is on my scale. At the moment I'm able to receive data from it when I press the print button. So the problem is not that I can't receive data from it but when I try to send data to the scale and expect an answer it doesn't work.

I have tried `serialPort.write(b'< LF >W< CR >')` and something happens on my scale but not the result that I want. It sets my scale to 0 and sends me dumb data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the SMA protocol is referring to the linefeed and carriage return characters as start and end codes (see http://www.asciitable.com/). Therefore with PySerial you should try:

```
serialPort.write(b'\x0AW\x0D')
```

\x in a string represents the start of a hexidecimal byte.

Comment: You can use `\n` for new-line/line-feed and `\r` for carriage return.